# elastic query scipting issue using painless

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless, esquery

A functional script query is working fine when i dont add certain scripts to it but it fails and returns > **[script] Too many dynamic script compilations within, max: [75/5m]; please use indexed, or scripts with parameters instead; this limit can be changed by the [script.max_compilations_rate] setting** > this error when i add mainly 2 scripts to it. Also this is not happening everytime, sometimes it works fine but most of the times it returns error. Below are the queries :

**Working query :**

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['profile_completed_score'].value >0 ? doc['profile_completed_score'].value * 0.15 : 0"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "if(!doc['profile_pic'].empty)return 10; return 0;"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "gauss": {
            "city_geolocation": {
              "origin": {
                "lat": "28.536000",
                "lon": "77.391000"
              },
              "scale": "100km",
              "offset": "100km",
              "decay": 0.0001
            }
          },
          "weight": 15
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "def designation=0; if(doc['designation_name.keyword'].value != null && doc['designation_name.keyword'].value==params.designation) { designation=30; } else { if(doc['designation_name.keyword'].value != null && (doc['designation_name.keyword'].value.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.designation.toUpperCase())>-1 || params.designation.toUpperCase().indexOf(doc['designation_name.keyword'].value.toUpperCase())>-1)) designation=15; } return designation;",
              "params": {
                "designation": "Technical Manager"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "def visited=0;def vscore=0;if(!doc['visited_event'].empty && doc['visited_event'].values.contains(params.fact))visited=10;if(!doc['avg_visitor_score'].empty)vscore=doc['avg_visitor_score'].value*0.2; return visited+vscore;",
              "params": {
                "fact": "13039"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "from": 0
}
```

Query returning error most of times :

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['profile_completed_score'].value >0 ? doc['profile_completed_score'].value * 0.15 : 0"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "if(!doc['profile_pic'].empty)return 10; return 0;"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "gauss": {
            "city_geolocation": {
              "origin": {
                "lat": "28.536000",
                "lon": "77.391000"
              },
              "scale": "100km",
              "offset": "100km",
              "decay": 0.0001
            }
          },
          "weight": 15
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "def designation=0; if(doc['designation_name.keyword'].value != null && doc['designation_name.keyword'].value==params.designation) { designation=30; } else { if(doc['designation_name.keyword'].value != null && (doc['designation_name.keyword'].value.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.designation.toUpperCase())>-1 || params.designation.toUpperCase().indexOf(doc['designation_name.keyword'].value.toUpperCase())>-1)) designation=15; } return designation;",
              "params": {
                "designation": "Technical Manager"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
           "script": {
              "source": "if(!doc['email_active'].empty && doc['email_active'].toInstant().toEpochMilli()/(params.divi) >= (params.epochtime)) return 30; return 0;",
              "params": {
                "divi": 1000,
                "epochtime": 1607863137
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "if((!doc['checkin_edition'].empty && doc['checkin_edition'].contains(params.fact))) return 30; return 0;",
              "params": {
                "fact": "1330689"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "def visited=0;def vscore=0;if(!doc['visited_event'].empty && doc['visited_event'].values.contains(params.fact))visited=10;if(!doc['avg_visitor_score'].empty)vscore=doc['avg_visitor_score'].value*0.2; return visited+vscore;",
              "params": {
                "fact": "13039"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "from": 0
}
```

Any kind of help is much appriciated.

[enter image description here][1]

Thanks//

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LMRj.png**strong text**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> [script] Too many dynamic script compilations within, max: [75/5m]; please use indexed, or scripts with parameters instead; this limit can be changed by the [script.max_compilations_rate] setting

The problems stems from the verbatim scripts in your `script_score` queries. If you read the error you're getting, the important part is **please use indexed, or scripts with parameters instead**

So what you should do is to [store scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#script-stored-scripts) so they are compiled only once.

```
POST _scripts/my-script
{
   "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "source": "doc['profile_completed_score'].value >0 ? doc['profile_completed_score'].value * 0.15 : 0"
   }
}
```

And then you can reference them by id in your queries

```
  "functions": [
    {
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "id": "my-script"
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks Val,
I tried what you suggested. stored all scripts and used them using id in my query. still its giving same error//
Anyother option you can suggest?

Comment: You need to store all your scripts, otherwise you'll keep getting this error